# Which is the fastest magical creature?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

I think it might be a tossup between a dragon and a phoenix but I would like it if there was something in canon about this.

Comment: Fastest by what measure?

Comment: Dragons don't disapparate, elves do, so do humans.

Comment: @Alex you load all creatures with a coconut and you make them travel from Africa to Britain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ignoring those creatures that are able to *simply Apparate from place to place [almost instantaneously](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/whats-the-speed-of-apparation)* (which includes the **Phoenix**, the **Diricawl**, the **Elf** and the **Wizard**), the fastest seen is probably the **Zouwo**.

> *The Zouwu is a monstrously large feline beast—as big as an elephant—with a striped body, scraggly mane, four fangs that curl up out of its mouth, and long sharp claws. Perhaps its most distinctive feature is its disproportionately long and ruffled multicolored tail. Native to China, **Zouwus are incredibly powerful and fast, capable of traveling 1,000 miles in a day.** The Zouwu in Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald was captured by Skender, the owner and Ringmaster of the wizarding world’s Circus Arcanus, and bears the scars of its abuse.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Beware! New Beasts Ahead in “Crimes of Grindelwald”](http://www.mugglenet.com/2018/08/beware-new-beasts-ahead-in-crimes-of-grindelwald/)</sup></sub>

Other contenders mentioned in the original [Fantastic Beasts book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them) include the **Nogtail** (albeit presumably over a much shorter distance)

> Nogtails are demons found in rural areas right across Europe, Russia
> and America. They resemble stunted piglets with long legs, thick,
> stubby tails and narrow black eyes. The Nogtail will creep into a sty
> and suckle an ordinary sow alongside her own young. The longer the
> Nogtail is left undetected and the bigger it grows, the longer the
> blight on the farm into which it has entered. T**he Nogtail is
> exceptionally fast and difficult to catch,** though if chased beyond the
> boundaries of a farm by a pure white dog, it will never return. The
> Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures (Pest
> Sub-Division) keeps a dozen albino bloodhounds for this purpose.

The **Snidget** (on which the Golden Snitch is based)

> The Golden Snidget is an extremely rare, protected species of bird.
> Completely round, with a very long, thin beak and glistening,
> jewel-like red eyes, **the Golden Snidget is an extremely fast flier**
> that can change direction with uncanny speed and skill, owing to the
> rotational joints of its wings.

and the **Winged Horse** (of which there are multiple varieties including the Thestral)

> Winged horses exist worldwide. There are many different breeds,
> including the Abraxan (immensely powerful giant palominos), the
> Aethonan (chestnut, popular in Britain and Ireland), **the Granian (grey
> and particularly fast)** and the rare Thestral (black, possessed of the
> power of invisibility and considered unlucky by many wizards). As with
> the Hippogriff, the owner of a winged horse is required to perform a
> Disillusionment Charm upon it at regular intervals.

And presumably the usual run of flying beasties like the **Hippogriff** and various **Dragons** although their *speed* is apparently not worthy of mention.

Comment: Where is it stated that apparition is instantaneous? The books make it rather clear that it takes some non-negligible time...

Comment: @Cœur - For minor spelling mistakes, it probably easiest to use the [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/202415/edit) command

Comment: @Cœur - Top tip, add a innocuous word. "*is apparently not worthy of [specific] mention*". "*multiple varieties including the [famous] Thestral*" if you need to increase the letter count

Comment: @Cœur: Exactly; that passage from HBP was what I was thinking of.

Comment: What about Billywigs? *It is around half an inch long and a vivid sapphire blue, although its speed is such that it is rarely noticed by Muggles and often not by 
wizards until they have been stung.*

Comment: @Alex - If I can "*barely see it*" (due to its speed) then it's not moving at 1000mph. At best it's moving at a fraction of that.

Comment: @Valorum The quote says "1,000 miles in a **day**".

Comment: So the Zouwus can travel travel 41.6mph (66.9kph) or if it observes an 8 hour work day... 125mph (201kph)?

Comment: @Skooba - That doesn't seem very fast at all, now that you do the math. It's just slightly faster than a horse

Comment: @Valorum I wonder if the top speed of broom sticks is out there (or can be reversed engineered) we can figure out how fast a Snitch goes then apply that to the Snidget. The only problem is that would assume brooms and Snitches haven't gotten faster over the years...

Comment: @Skooba From Prisoner of Azkaban: *THE FIREBOLT HAS AN ACCELERATION OF 150 MILES AN HOUR IN TEN SECONDS*

Comment: A horse travelling 50 miles in a day would be unusual. The Zouwu is more than a little bit faster.  One can't simply take a horse's maximum galloping speed and multiply it by long time periods. The best human sprinters, like Usain Bolt, can do 27 mph - do you think they can run 600 miles in a day?